# How to get pass of the joi validation if the data values are not defined?

Tags: node.js, validation

I am using Joi Validator for validating my api's in node.js. I have a search api where I am passing few params but it is not mandatory that every time same query params will be passed.

for e.g.
Below is my query params for my search api :-

```
getTaskBySearch: {
query: Joi.object({
  appId: Joi.string().uuid().required().optional(),
  assignedTo: Joi.string().optional(),
  name: Joi.string().optional(),
  limit: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
  offset: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
  sortField: Joi.string().required(),
  sortBy: Joi.string().required()
})
```

}

So it's not mandatory that "**name**" and "**assignedTo**" will be always passed in the query params. In future more keys can also get added dynamically. So my api will not be aware about the query param keys.

Problem :- Hence I want to write a validation for 4 keys on mandatory basis i.e. "**limit**", "**offset**", "**sortField**", "**sortBy**" apart from these 4 keys I don't want any validation for any other keys. So I want to keep only 4 keys in my validation query :-

```
 getTaskBySearch: {
 query: Joi.object({
  limit: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
  offset: Joi.number().integer().min(1).required(),
  sortField: Joi.string().required(),
  sortBy: Joi.string().required()
})
```

}

But if i am not keeping name/assignedTo in the query and if i am passing in the query params from ui/postman then i am getting error as below :-

```
{
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "Validation Failed",
"statusCode": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"details": {
    "query": [
        {
            "message": "\"name\" is not allowed",
            "path": [
                "name"
            ],
            "type": "object.unknown",
            "context": {
                "child": "name",
                "label": "name",
                "value": "Sweta",
                "key": "name"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Any leads will be very helpful.